# Make Emacs 25 menu bar integrate with Unity

Tags: menu-bar

I recently upgraded to Emacs 25. With Emacs 24, the menu bar never integrated with Unity. Emacs always had its own menu bar – Gnome 2 style. One of the first things I noticed after upgrading to Emacs 25 was that the menu bar integrated with Unity.

However, since then it sometimes integrated with Unity and sometimes doesn't in a seemingly random fashion.

How do I make Emacs's menu bar always integrate with Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fast one. I struggled with this for quite a bit but a few minutes after posting the question, I found the answer myself.

I got a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + ß</kbd>) for opening Emacs in addition to the default shortcut Unity provides (<kbd>Ctrl + 4</kbd> because it's the 4th application in my launcher). Every time I use Unity's shortcut, Emacs' menu bar integrates nicely with Unity. Every time I use my own shortcut, it doesn't.

I then found that the exec line of Emacs' desktop file looks like this:

```
Exec=emacs25 %F
```

My own shortcut, however, executes `emacs`. I removed Emacs 24 and after launching Emacs via `emacs`, it actually launches Emacs 25, according to `Help → About Emacs`. Yet, the menu bar behaves differently.

When launching `emacs25` from the command line, Emacs' menu bar integrates with Unity just like it does when using Unity's shortcut or when using the button in the launcher. I will now change my own shortcut to execute `emacs25`.

If anyone knows why Emacs behaves in this weird fashion, please let me know.

### Development version

Edit: If you want to use the current development version of Emacs, first install it normally (with `sudo make install`). Then open a terminal, enter `emacs` (but don't hit enter) and press tab twice. You will be shown several program names, including one with with a version number. In my case, this is `emacs-27.0.50`. Then open `/usr/local/share/applications/emacs.desktop` and adapt the Exec line. So

```
Exec=emacs %F
```

becomes:

```
Exec=emacs-27.0.50 %F
```

Save the file and open Emacs as usual via its desktop file. The menus will be integrated into the window bars.

Comment: `emacs25` isn't a normal binary name for a compiled emacs. I would think it is consistent that `emacs` and `emacs-25.3` (or as appropriate for the version) are the two executable names which are built. Assuming that `emacs25` isn't a typo, you may find that `emacs` and `emacs-25.3` are identical, and `emacs25` is something particular to Ubuntu which adds that Unity integration.

Comment: @phils Nope, they all eventually point to the same binary. `/usr/bin/emacs-25.325` on my machine.